# Where does the mass of particle that is decaying go?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

The particle of a heavy quark (such a s a bottom quark) into either an up or down is an actually change I'm mass (if I know what I'm talking about, which I don't think I do, but that's what this is for) where does mass go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns into kinetic energy a la $E = mc^2$. When a particle decays into a lighter particle, that lighter particle is usually traveling much faster than its parent particle was. So, for instance, at the LHC they'll catch particles that come out of a decay, add up their total energy (counting rest mass and kinetic energy), and use that to determine the mass of the particle that created them. (It's a lot more detailed than that of course, even without getting into the question of "how do they catch/measure all of this?")

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following link [Most Particles Decay — Yet Some Don’t!](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/why-do-particles-decay/most-particles-decay-yet-some-dont/) as a complement to the response above.